# Windows7 can't find libqjson.dll to run my Qt application

Tags: qt

I failed to run an Qt application compiled from QtCreator.
My windows7 notified: Can not find libqjson.dll on your computer to run this application.
What should I do with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, Windows cannot find this DLL so you need to put it in the same folder as your executable. More info there - http://qjson.sourceforge.net/get_it/windows.html